# Computing Womersley number

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

I'd like to know whether the blood flow is pulsatile in small capillaries present in tissues that lie away from the heart.
From the literature, I understand that the [Womersley number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Womersley_number) can be computed to find out if the flow profile will be pulsatile. Also, at small values of Womersley number, the flow becomes Poiseuille flow.

Womersley number, $\alpha = R\sqrt \frac{\rho \omega}{\mu}$

R is the radius

$\omega$ is the frequency

$\rho$ is the density and

$\mu$ is the viscosity

I am not sure how to determine the value of $\omega$ to compute $\alpha$.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

EDIT:
In the discussion below, the following has been suggested

> Power spectrum of the cardiogram will give you the frequencies in the
> pressure with their magnitudes -basically it is a Fourier transform
> applied to cardiogram data. Then you can transform these frequencies
> to Womersley number and you have a Womersley number vs Magnitude
> graph. From there, you can see if there are any frequencies which
> allow for pulsatile flow

The above-mentioned suggestion will give us the graph for Womersley number and pressure frequencies in the heart. But how do we use this information to infer the pressure frequencies, for example, in the liver or other tissues?

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: $\omega = \frac{\alpha^2 \mu}{R^2 \rho}$ ?

Comment: @andereBen I would like to compute $\alpha$

Comment: Isn't $\omega$ the heart rate in this case? If not, you can measure the distance between pressure spikes at a point to determine a frequency. Note that, I am not really familiar with vascular applications of CFD, so take my suggestions with a tablespoon of salt.

Comment: Hi @AbdullahAliSivas Yes, $\omega$ is the heart rate. But if I want to check if the flow is pulsatile in a tissue such as liver, I am not sure how $\omega$ should be estimated because I don't know if the pressure profile has spikes in blood vessels of the liver.

Comment: If you are worried about spikes, shouldn't a power spectrum of a cardiogram converted to a spectrum of Womersley number for the liver parameters give you exactly what you want? With this equipped you can then check if there are frequencies which allow for pulsatile flow.

Comment: @Bort Thank a lot for the response. I'm sorry I don't completely understand `shouldn't a power spectrum of a cardiogram converted to a spectrum of Womersley number for the liver parameters `. Could you please elaborate on this and share some references, if possible?

Comment: @Bort is potentially suggesting same thing as I do. But, obviously, they know more than I do about the topic and I may be wrong. Power spectrum of the cardiogram will give you the frequencies in the pressure with their magnitudes -basically it is a Fourier transform applied to cardiogram data. Then you can transform these frequencies to Womersley number and you have a Womersley number vs Magnitude graph. From there, you can see if there are any frequencies which allow for pulsatile flow. Bort, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Doing what is mentioned above in your comment will give us the graph for Womersley number and pressure frequencies in the heart. But how do we use this information to infer the pressure frequencies for example in the liver or other tissues? Thank you very much

Comment: That is, unfortunately, out of my expertise. I do not know enough human physiology to recommend a way to compute the pressure frequencies given the pressure frequencies in the heart. Can you edit and expand your question with a summary of the discussion here and your followup questions? It may get more attention.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas Thank you very much. I've made an edit

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas I by no means know more about the topic. Yes, you describe exactly the idea. I just came up with this because it is a very standard technique in different areas in physics. Practically speaking, if you use a cardiogram of the heart it will be a worst case estimation for frequencies, since pressure waves dissipate. So if the liver is far enough away from the heart, e.g. frequencies will have a reduced magnitude. So if you already have no pulsatile flow with those frequencies, you won't expect a pulsatile flow at the liver as well.

Comment: I suggest to migrate this question to physics stack exchange it is more appropriate there.

Comment: In most applications of physics frequency is considered to be the same when changing media.

Comment: @Bort Thank you very much for the explanation. `So if you already have no pulsatile flow with those frequencies, you won't expect a pulsatile flow at the liver as well.` I would like to proceed from here. I am not sure how where to look for the information on the cardiogram observed in capillaries of the heart. Suggestions or links to such data will be of great help.

Comment: @nicoguaro Thank you. Could you please explain a bit more on why frequency is considered to be the same? As Bort pointed out I believe the pressure waves would dissipate.

Comment: Can one of the moderators migrate my question to physics stack exchange?

Comment: @Natasha, nicoguaro is right. My words are misleading. Yes, the frequencies are the same. What I wanted to point out is, that the corresponding amplitude is reduced by dissipation.

Comment: @Bort Thank you very much for the clarification. I thought both frequency and amplitude might get altered.